# Excellent correlation, poor prediction

Tags: regression, self-study, correlation, prediction

could you please provide an example or give a relevant formula 
for the following situation: 
correlation between variables (x and y) is excellent, 
but the prediction of y by x values is poor, 
when using a linear regression model.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If so, please use the "self-study" tag.

Comment: I don't know what exactly do you mean by poor prediction, but prediction can be meaningless if you have outliers in your data, for example: construct data using formula y = -10x for x in (1, 2, ..., 20) and add point (1000, 1000) to the data. The corelation is 0.966, but linear regression model is following y = -116 + 1.1x, which is quite far from y = -10x.

Comment: "Excellent" and "poor," being purely qualitative, render this question too ambiguous to have an objective answer.  Please clarify your meanings of these words.

Comment: I saw this [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15983190) (3rd sentence) and I have no idea what 'excellent' and 'poor' is. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: That's the *abstract.*  The [article itself](http://diabetes.diabetesjournals.org/content/54/7/1914.long), which is freely viewable, makes it clear what the authors mean by "excellent" and "poor" and provides specific answers to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer will depend on what you (or whoever gave you this assignment) means by "poor prediction".

However, assuming that you were just given this as an assignment, @Tomek gave you one idea. Since this is self-study, I'll give some more hints, rather than complete answers.

You could also take a look at the Anscombe quartet. Other possibilities may spring from other violations of the assumptions in regression. Think about these and about what violating each could mean. Think about what might happen if the data were more suitable for logistic regression.

Comment: +1 - The advice to look at the [Anscombe quartet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) seems particularly valuable in this context. Similar sets with higher correlation can be constructed.

Answer (score 2):

The full quote is worth including:

> The quantitative insulin-sensitivity check index (QUICKI) has an excellent linear correlation with the glucose clamp index of insulin sensitivity (SI(Clamp)) that is better than that of many other surrogate indexes. However, correlation between a surrogate and reference standard may improve as variability between subjects in a cohort increases (i.e., with an increased range of values). Correlation may be excellent even when prediction of reference values by the surrogate is poor.

This sounds like a restriction of range issue. Here's [a little Java demonstration of how range restriction affects Pearson's $r$](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/describing_bivariate_data/restriction_demo.html).

Comment: Now I understand where the problem is. It's a great demo. Thanks a lot!